# Using AllowAnonymousAttribute with Swashbuckle

Tags: .net, swagger, swashbuckle

I am trying to add `Swagger` (via `Swashbuckle 5.6.0`) into a `.Net 4.5.1 WebAPI`.

I was able to get things working until I ran across a custom authorization filter via the new [ActionFilterAttribute](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/aspnet/hh834978(v%3Dvs.118)) attribute in the following `AdminController.cs`:

```
public class AdminController : BaseApiController
{
    [CustomAuthorize( )]
    [HttpGet]
    public GenericResponse ClearCache()
    {
        using (var businessAccess = IoCContainer.Resolve<IAdminBusinessAccess>())
        {
            var response = new GenericResponse();

            businessAccess.ClearCache();

            return response;
        }
    }
}

[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Class | AttributeTargets.Method, AllowMultiple = false, Inherited = true)]
public class CustomAuthorizeAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public Enumerations.SecurityCheck SecurityCheck { get; set; }
}
```

Now, my Swagger UI stalls on fetching resources until Chrome crashes. If I comment out this `ActionFilterAttribute` attribute, everything works. Does anyone know how to use Swashbuckle or Swagger with authorization attributes?

Comment: I tried to reproduce what you are experiencing with `ActionFilterAttribute` but no luck... it seems to work for me:
https://github.com/heldersepu/Swagger-Net-Test/blob/master/Swagger_Test/Controllers/ActionFilterController.cs and here is the UI
http://swagger-net-test.azurewebsites.net/swagger/ui/index#/ActionFilter/ActionFilter_Post maybe it is a combination of other factors I did not include on mine

Comment: Ah! You're right - it does work! It looks like the reason m swagger breaks is actually due to complex Entity Framework models. I'll give you the bounty for putting in so much work.

Comment: `Swashbuckle 5.6.0` is very old, look into swagger-net: https://www.nuget.org/packages/Swagger-Net ... I maintain that project, already fixed countless bugs and I'm using latest of the swagger-ui ... if you get any errors just report it on GitHub and we can get to the bottom of the bug. I have used EF and no issues so far, but your models could be very complex with a scenario we never considered/tested.

Comment: @HelderSepulveda ah you grace me with your presence! Also I didn't know about swagger-net ...I'll look into using that instead of Swashbuckle thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use authorization without the need for `ActionFilterAttribute` like this:

```
public class KeyAuthorizeAttribute : AuthorizeAttribute
{
    protected override bool IsAuthorized(HttpActionContext actionContext)
    {
        IEnumerable<string> apiKey;
        if (actionContext.Request.Headers.TryGetValues("apiKey", out apiKey))
        {
            return apiKey.First() == "123"; 
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

https://github.com/heldersepu/nhc-noaa/blob/master/nhc-noaa/App_Start/KeyAuthorizeAttribute.cs

And then on the actions:

```
    [KeyAuthorize]
    public Test PostEcho([FromBody] List<Test> tests)
    {
        return tests.FirstOrDefault();
    }
```

last on your swagger.config

```
c.ApiKey("apiKey", "header", "API Key Authentication", typeof(KeyAuthorizeAttribute));
```

and you should get a nice Authorize box on the UI:
https://nhc-noaa.azurewebsites.net/swagger/ui/index
[image]

Is that `ActionFilterAttribute` a hard requirement for you?

Comment: Unfortunately yes `ActionFilterAttribute` is a hard requirement as this is an existing legacy solution with a tight deadline for development. So, we don't want to change our authentication approach too much but we were hoping to add swagger with minimal effort.